# Build target randomly added to Xcode scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, cocoapods

I am developing an iPhone app using Xcode 5 and CocoaPods. I have a scheme and target called `Oahu` that I run my tests against. Accordingly, I am not surprised to see my two test targets present to be built in the scheme's build phase. However, there is a fourth build target that cannot be removed:

[image]

When I run tests, all four targets are built, and the test targets are run against the last, incorrect one, `Ku`.

And after closing Xcode, deleting the contents of the `DerivedData` directory, and deleting all the `*userdata` files in my project directory (`find ./ | grep userdata | xargs rm -rf`), I still have an extraneous build target:

[image]

Notice that it now included my `Production` target and I also had unchecked `Find Implicit Dependencies`.

I've looked through all my build settings, `Oahu.xcscheme`, and `project.pbxproj`, but I can't find anything that would leave to this behavior. Unchecking the scheme's Build Option `Find Implicit Dependencies` has no effect.

This `Oahu` scheme is the only one that has this problem – the `Ku` and `Production` schemes only have their corresponding targets – though if I duplicate the `Oahu` scheme, it also has this problem.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found all my build and test problems were related to having the same binary name. Renaming the binaries produced by each target to be unique fixed the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit lost with this answer here... What exactly did you have in mind by "binary name"

Comment: I think he meant the Product name. I tried with the product name and it seems working now for me.

Comment: Yes, set Product Name to be the same for all build configs and you should be fine.

Comment: Well, what if I want the same product name, e.g. for an AppStore and Retail build?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. In my case the additional target appeared in the build settings of the scheme's target. You can search for the undesired target name there, I found mine under BUNLDE_LOADER and TEST_HOST. It got fixed after I deleted the settings.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because the target was listed under Target Dependencies under the Build Phases of my test target.